# Does Rails have porter stemmer (english stemming)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to find anything in rails that allows stemming of works.

For example the following words would all get converted to `comput`

```
computers
computing
compute
computer
```

Side note: if the stemming is based on Porter Stemmer algo that would be great (as that is what I use in PHP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really are looking for a ruby stemmer and of those there are quite a few.

- [fast-stemmer](https://github.com/romanbsd/fast-stemmer) actually uses porter stemmer algorithm
- [ruby-stemmer](https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer)

Comment: Really dumb question: Do I include it in my Gemfile file in rails for it to work?

Comment: Found it... there is a 'fast-stemmer' gem for rails :)  https://github.com/romanbsd/fast-stemmer

Answer (score 1):

There was a stremmer gem; here's a list if NLP tools:

http://mendicantbug.com/2009/09/13/nlp-resources-for-ruby/

(Not an answer since I haven't used the gem in years, don't know if it works on 1.9.)